# Can employer view images in email on personal device in personal email account over wifi?

Tags: wifi

Accidentally opened my personal email on company wifi. Had received a message with a suggestive but not graphic image in it, but still what I'd consider inappropriate use of wifi.

It was mail from a personal non-company outlook account using the iOS mail app to view it. This is not a company device either, totally personal with nothing installed from the company on it.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is secure it was probably not possible to view the email content in transit or on your device,

That you used your device to access personal email could probably be determined. if they were watching network traffic.

Comment: Heya thanks for your answer. What is "secure" in this context?

Comment: Unless you work for the NSA. or your employer has installed montoring software on it your iPAD  it's most probably secure.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the configuration of your mail reader application. Email protocols are truely disconnected protocols. First the sender application sends the message to its own mail server, which transmits it (optionaly through relays) to the receiver server. This first part uses the SMTP protocol and the communication between the client and its server can be SSL encrypted.

Later, the receiver application contacts its mail server through the POP or IMAP protocol to retrieve the messages. If you have used your corporate wifi, this part can be seen by the network admins. If you use IMAP+SSL, the man-in-the-middle (here the corporate admin) will know that you have retreived an email through their network, and what your mail server is. But the content of the message will be SSL encrypted so not readable. Is you have not configured SSL on that part, the message is transmitted is clear form and is accessible to the network admins.

For the possible outcomes, IANAL, but at least in France a *reasonable* use of corporate resources for private communication is normally accepted, and as the *image* of the corporation is not involved, the employer shall not use the content of a private message against an employee unless the usage is clearly exaggerated, or they have serious reasons to suspect an illegal content. On the other hand, sending *inappropiate* content from a corporate email account would implicate the corporation *image*, and would be a professional fault.

Comment: Can't say I've done any setting up of that kind of thing so may not being looking to good for me

Comment: Also doesn't seem like I can enable SSL on outlook accounts through the iOS mail app either

Comment: many applications will enable it automatically.